# How to subdivide a shape into sections of a given size

Tags: javascript, math, graphics, graph, charts

I'm currently trying to build a kind of pie chart / voronoi diagram hybrid (in canvas/javascript) .I don't know if it's even possible. I'm very new to this, and I haven't tried any approaches yet.

Assume I have a circle, and a set of numbers 2, 3, 5, 7, 11.

I want to subdivide the circle into sections equivalent to the numbers (much like a pie chart) but forming a lattice / honeycomb like shape.

[image]

Is this even possible? Is it ridiculously difficult, especially for someone who's only done some basic pie chart rendering?

Comment: Ouch. Best of luck with that one!

Comment: you should be more specific about the "honeycomb", basically, how should it should look like when the number of sections is some number `n`?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, and not too difficult. Only: How are you gooing to choose the [generator points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) that define the shapes? This eventually could need higher geometry - the pie chart is just a special (euclidean) voronoi with the points on a circle.

Comment: By honeycomb I just meant a circle split into angular shapes. How I'm going to choose the generator points is part of the problem. I know the numbers, and I know the area, and therefore I know the percentage of area each section takes up - but there are lots of random ways these points could fit into this circle. For example, in the simple version above, 2 could be swapped with 5.

Comment: It doesn't seem impossible, but I see some difficulties.  For one, your solution won't be unique, so different people could give totally different solutions.  For another, making sure that the areas on a circle are the same seem like it would be a real headache.  It's going to take some actual geometry to make it work.  Are you married to the circle?  Because I think a square would be much easier to work with.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a circle - It's actually supposed to fit inside a rough ellipse shape. I thought it would be easier to start with a circle and move away from that. Maybe a more angular shape like a hexagon might work, but a square will not.

Comment: From a perceptual point of view (that is, having people understand and compare the numbers that you're drawing), the result will be worse than pie-charts, which are already worse than bars. I would recommend against doing this...

Comment: Thanks tucuxi but its not actually for a chart, it's intended as a tag cloud. the areas represent a number of articles under a certain category.

Answer (score 0):

This is my view on this after a quick look.

A general solution, assuming there are to be `n` polygons with `k` vertices/edges, will depend on the solution to `n` equations, where each equation has no more than `2nk`, (but exactly `2k` non-zero) variables. The variables in each polygon's equation are the same `x_1, x_2, x_3... x_nk` and `y_1, y_2, y_3... y_nk` variables. Exactly four of `x_1, x_2, x_3... x_nk` have non-zero coefficients and exactly four of `y_1, y_2, y_3... y_nk` have non-zero coefficients for each polygon's equation. `x_i` and `y_i` are bounded differently depending on the parent shape.. For the sake of simplicity, we'll assume the shape is a circle. The boundary condition is: `(x_i)^2 + (y_i)^2 <= r^2`

Note: I say no more than `2nk`, because I am unsure of the lowerbound, but know that it can not be more than `2nk`. This is a result of polygons, as a requirement, sharing vertices.

The equations are the collection of definite, but variable-bounded, integrals representing the area of each polygon, with the area equal for the `ith` polygon:

`A_i = pi*r^2/S_i`

where `r` is the radius of the parent circle and `S_i` is the number assigned to the polygon, as in your diagram.

The four separate pairs of `(x_j,y_j)`, both with non-zero coefficients in a polygon's equation will yield the vertices for the polygon.

This may prove to be considerably difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Is the boundary fixed from the beginning, or can you deform it a bit?

If I had to solve this, I would sort the areas from large to small. Then, starting with the largest area, I would first generate a random convex polygon (vertices along a circle) with the required size. The next area would share an edge with the first area, but would be otherwise also random and convex. Each polygon after that would choose an existing edge from already-present polygons, and would also share any 'convex' edges that start from there (where 'convex edge' is one that, if used for the new polygon, would result in the new polygon still being convex).

By evaluating different prospective polygon positions for 'total boundary approaches desired boundary', you can probably generate a cheap approximation to your initial goal. This is quite similar to what word-clouds do: place things incrementally from largest to smallest while trying to fill in a more-or-less enclosed space.

Answer (score 0):

Given a set of voronio centres (i.e. a list of the coordinates of the centre for each one), we can calculate the area closest to each centre:

```
area[i] = areaClosestTo(i,positions)
```

Assume these are a bit wrong, because we haven't got the centres in the right place. So we can calculate the error in our current set by comparing the areas to the ideal areas:

```
var areaIndexSq = 0;
var desiredAreasMagSq = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < areas.length; ++i) {
    var contrib = (areas[i] - desiredAreas[i]);
    areaIndexSq += contrib*contrib;
    desiredAreasMagSq += desiredAreas[i]*desiredAreas[i];
}
var areaIndex = Math.sqrt(areaIndexSq/desiredAreasMagSq);
```

This is the vector norm of the difference vector between the areas and the desiredAreas. Think of it like a measure of how good a least squares fit line is.

We also want some kind of honeycomb pattern, so we can call that `honeycombness(positions)`, and get an overall measure of the quality of the thing (this is just a starter, the weighting or form of this can be whatever floats your boat):

```
var overallMeasure = areaIndex + honeycombnessIndex;
```

Then we have a mechanism to know how bad a guess is, and we can combine this with a mechanism for modifying the positions; the simplest is just to add a random amount to the x and y coords of each centre. Alternatively you can try moving each point towards neighbour areas which have an area too high, and away from those with an area too low.

This is not a straight solve, but it requires minimal maths apart from calculating the area closest to each point, and it's approachable. The difficult part may be recognising local minima and dealing with them.

Incidentally, it should be fairly easy to get the start points for the process; the centroids of the pie slices shouldn't be too far from the truth.

A definite plus is that you could use the intermediate calculations to animate a transition from pie to voronoi.